# getting percentage of cpu used with powershell counter

Tags: powershell, cpu, performancecounter

I am trying to get with powershell script, the percentage of cpu used by my server. I developp a solution by searching on the net, but I am still a debutant and not sure about the real meaning of the value I get with this solution. I did some research on the net, but answers are still giving me more doubt.

This is my script :

```
function GetPercentageOfCpuUsed()
{
 $value = Get-Counter "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time"
 $Value = $value.CounterSamples[0].CookedValue  
 return $Value
}
```

Is the "value" returned corresponds to the percentage of cpu used by my server at the time when I run my powershell script ?

Answer (score 0):

`\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time` is a performance counter that tells you the percentage of time the processors were busy during the sampling interval (Source: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938593.aspx). For instance, in a 4-core system, one CPU with 100% usage and the rest of the CPUs running entirely idle should give you 25%. You can also monitor this counter live using the Performance Monitor MMC of Windows to get an impression how it behaves. According to the Technet article above, this figure is also the same as the CPU Usage figure in the Task Manager.

Comment: so do i have to multiply the number i get from get-counter by the name of cores i have? the get-counter number just seems to be totally of. it gives me ranges from 1-3% all the time but task-manager shows like 20-30% which doesn't make any sense why no other source says how to calculate with the get-counter number